# Portable credentials in Custom-Ubuntu-DVD-Bootable

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, laptop

I have created a customizable Ubuntu ISO which I want to run on my TV-connected-old-laptop. I Don't want to have anything lingering after a restart so I have a bootable-customized-ubuntu (using Cubic) and after Ubuntu comes up, i have a startup script running which does the following.

1. Setup screen appropriate resolution
2. Disable Laptop display
3. Disable screensaver
4. Ignore laptop lid close
5. Set appropriate audio output
6. Set appropriate timezone
7. Setup Chrome profile files
8. Install Chrome
9. Open Browser

On #7 I'm extracting the Default directory (which I had back'd up earlier with my google-logins). But google detects that I have a new machine and it forces me to re login again. How to avoid this? Is there any other way to cleanly & securely do this?

**Note:** *No other user has physical-access to this laptop so local security is not a concern.*